# How to stack query results into single cell formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'd like to generate a URL based on a list of items that will change over time and I'm having a little trouble. My data looks like this:

| Items | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1 | Item1URL |
| Item 2 | Item2URL |
| Item 3 | Item3URL |

and I'd like to generate a URL that looks like this: "website.com/?items&Item1URL&Item2URL&Item3URL"

Right now I have this formula, but it only returns "website.com/items?&Item1URL"

```
="https://www.website.com/items?"&query(A3:B,"SELECT B WHERE A <> ''")
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Try JOIN function. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Use `textjoin()`, like this:

`="https://www.website.com/items?" & textjoin("&", true, B3:B)`